# What happens if $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ are zero in the definition of the limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

Can someone explain what happens when epsilon and delta are equal to zero in the definition of limits using epsilon-delta?

Comment: They cannot be for it to be about limits:  limits are about what happens nearby, but never **at** the point.

Answer (score 1):

Reminder of the definition: $\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = L$ means:
for all $\epsilon >0$, there exists a $\delta >0$ such that $$0<|x - a| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - L| < \epsilon $$

If $\delta > 0$ and $\epsilon = 0$ it means that the value of  the function should be exactly the target value in the neighbourhood of the point where you take the limit.

If $\delta = 0$, then the "neighbourhood" is just one point, and the definition of the limit reduces to "if $x=y$, then $f(x)=f(y)$"; this is useless.