# prove x/(x^2 + 1) is continuous at x = -1 using the definition of continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Prove  that the function $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{x}{x^2+1}$ is continuous at $x=-1$ using the  definition of continuity.

My attempt:

Need show that $\forall {\epsilon > 0},\exists {\delta > 0}$ s.t $\forall {x \in R },\ |x - (-1)| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(-1)| < \epsilon.\\
|f(x) - f(-1)| = |\frac{x}{x^2 + 1} - \frac{-1}{2}| = |\frac{2x - (-1)(x^2 + 1)}{2(x^2 + 1)}| = |\frac{2x + x^2 + 1)}{2(x^2 + 1)}| = |\frac{(x+1)^2}{2(x^2 + 1)}|\\
|\frac{(x+1)^2}{2(x^2 + 1)}| < |\frac{(x+1)^2}{(x^2 + 1)}| <  |(x+1)^2| \text{ since } (x^2 + 1) \text{ is at least 1}\\
|(x+1)^2| = |x + 1|^2 < \epsilon \\ 
|x + 1| < \sqrt{\epsilon}$

Therefore set $\delta = \sqrt{\epsilon} \text{ and } \forall {\epsilon > 0}, \ \forall {x \in R }, |x - (-1)| < \sqrt{\epsilon} \implies |f(x) - f(-1)| < \epsilon$

is this a valid way of proving this? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Your proof and choice of $\delta$ are OK. There's one minor issue. The inequalities below are non-strict since you have equality when $x=-1$:
$$\left|\frac{\left(x+1\right)^2}{2\left(x^2+1\right)}\right|\leq \left|\frac{\left(x+1\right)^2}{x^2+1}\right|\leq\left|\left(x+1\right)^2\right|  $$
This doesn't change the rest of the proof.

Comment: Strictly, the epsilon-delta definition should have $\textbf{0}<|x-c|<\delta$, so $x$ shouldn't be able to take the value of $x=-1$ [(Question 958412)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/958412/what-happens-if-epsilon-and-delta-are-zero-in-the-definition-of-the-limit). But indeed, the OP should have included that in the definition.

Comment: @Jam No, OP is proving continuity using the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of it, not the limit definition. So $x$ can be $-1$.

Comment: @Jam see the link for the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Weierstrass_and_Jordan_definitions_(epsilon%E2%80%93delta)_of_continuous_functions

Comment: The value of a function at a point doesn't affect the limit of the function at the point. So, we would only take $x=-1$ when examining the value of the function, not the limit. If you allow $0\color{red}{=}|x-(-1)|<\delta$, the epsilon-delta definition of the limit breaks down, e.g., $f(x)=\begin{cases}1,&x=-1\\\text{undefined},&\text{else}\end{cases}$ would have a "limit" at $x=-1$ since we can always take $|x-(-1)|<\delta$ despite only being defined at one point.

Comment: @Jam Yes but that applies when we're taking limits. We're not doing this here. OP is using a direct $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of *continuity* which is cited in the link in my previous comment. Since $f(-1)$ has to be defined, there's no need to impose the $0<|x-(-1)|$ requirement. Of course, if you want, you can prove that the limit at $-1$ is $-1/2$ in which case we'd have that requirement. It's equivalent, really.

Comment: I didn't realise there were different definitions. Thanks for enlightening me.

Answer (score 0):

The proof looks correct to me. And I think it's about as neat and direct a proof as you could get.

However, in the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of the limit, we should have $\textbf{0}<|x-c|<\delta$, since we are interested in the behaviour *around* the point, not *at* the point. See [(Question 958412)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/958412/what-happens-if-epsilon-and-delta-are-zero-in-the-definition-of-the-limit). Alternatively, as **bjorn93** has pointed out, you could change your strict inequalities to non-strict ones.